# Finding an elementary function growing asymptotically as the integral of a sequential product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, series-expansion

I am trying to understand how grows the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ `Integrate[(1-Product[1-Exp[-2*j*t/(k*(k+1))], {j, 1, k}]), {t,0,\[Infinity]}]` for $k\to\infty$. However, the following command, takes too much time:

```
Series[Integrate[(1-Product[1-Exp[-2*j*t/(k*(k+1))], {j, 1, k}]), {t,0,\[Infinity]}],{k,\[Infinity],1}]
```

---

**Question:** How can I modify the command? (If there is not such elementary function, I would be interested in finding a function $g(k)=\Theta(f(k))$ for $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Your `jt` needs to be written either `j t` or `j*t`

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define

```
f[k_,kx_]:=k*(k+1)/2*Integrate[1-Product[1-Exp[-j*t],{j,1,kx}],{t,0,Infinity}]
```

The integral given by OP is equal to `f[k,k]`. To see this, substitute $t$ with $tk(k+1)/2$.

One can estimate `f[k,k]` as follows:

- A lower bound is given by

  ```
  f[k,1]
  (* 1/2 k (1+k) *)
  ```
- An upper bound is given by

  ```
  f[k,Infinity]
  (* k*(1+k)/2*Integrate[1-QPochhammer[E^(-t),E^(-t)],{t,0,Infinity}] *)
  ```

  The integral that appears here can be evaluated numerically

  ```
  f[k,Infinity]/.Integrate->NIntegrate
  (* 0.627599 k (1+k) *)
  ```

We conclude that `0.5*k(k+1) <= f[k,k] <= 0.63*k(k+1)` for all integers $k \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know whether this suggestion is correct, but for very large k the term in Exp is very small, so it could be expanded (or not?)

```
jj[(1 - Product[
    1 - Normal[Series[Exp[-2 j t/(k*(k + 1))], {t, 0, 1}]], 
{j, 1,k}]), {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

but the integration will not work, at least on my system.